# Wallpapers' s folder in XFCE4

Tags: arch-linux, directory, path, xfce

I've just installed XFCE4 on Arch Linux, now I'd like to add an image in the wallpaper folder, someone know the full path. I'm searching, but I haven't found yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wallpapers should be in `/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops`

if there isn't this folder you must create: go in the folder, right bottom on the mouse, open here terminal and digit

```
sudo mkdir backdrops
```

Then exit from the terminal, search your wallpaper and open terminal

```
sudo cp /path/image.png /usr/share/xfce4/backdrops
```

**EDIT:** or `usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/` here you'll find the standard wallpapers